# How to auto propdel svn:executable?

Tags: svn, cygwin, executable

Subversion has a feature to set the `svn:executable` property
on newly added files that have exec-permission.
Is there some configuration that controls this behavior?

I know how to set a property on certain files using config `[autoprop]`, but I see no way to unset it.

It is particularly irritating when the svn client on Cygwin believes that all windows files are executable, and populates the repository with executable texts and C files.

Is there any trick to inhibit this, apart from being careful and chmod the files before adding them to svn?

Answer (score 2):

Basically to chmod -x run: `svn propdel svn:executable file`

```
svn propset svn:executable src/*.C 
svn propset svn:executable src/*.txt
```

Comment: are you sure it toggles? For me, any value just sets '*'

Comment: Bad luck, `svn propset svn:executable src/*.C` will take the first of `src/*.C` as a property value for the rest of the files, and this value is always ignored.

`svn propdel` works, of course. However it only can be done at command line, there is no correspondent option in `[auto-props]`.

Comment: ahh jokes! I guess you will need to wrap it in a shell script :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Victor Parmar's idea, I have written the following wrapper script `svn-add`, which tries to detect actual executables and removes the `svn:executable` property for the rest when adding files.

```
#!/bin/bash

svn add "$@" || exit $?

if [ "$(uname -o 2>/dev/null)" = "Cygwin" ]; then
    for filespec
    do
        if [ -f "$filespec" ]; then
            extension=${filespec##*.}
            if [[ ";${PATHEXT^^};" = *";.${extension^^};"* ]]; then
                echo "$filespec is executable"
            else
                # According to Windows, the file is not executable, but Cygwin
                # treats all files on the Windows file systems as executable
                # (unless explicitly modified via chmod), and Subversion's
                # Automatic Property Setting feature adds svn:executable
                # properties. Strip them off for this file.
                svn propdel svn:executable "$filespec"
            fi
        fi
    done
fi
```